# How do I wire my Fostex PM0.5n?

Tags: xlr, fostex

I'm setting up my monitoring speakers PM0.5n and I'm wondering about the correct wiring of the cable to plug into the combined xlr/jack connector.
I couldn't find the manual online, and the manual for the PM0.5d (d instead of n) doesn't seem to answer my question.

I want to use a TRS (jack) connector for each speaker, each one will receive an unbalanced signal.
The TRS female connector on the speaker seems to be a three points connector.
Should I use Tip/Ring for signal / signal ground and Sleeve as shielding (i.e. chassis ground), or should I use Tip for signal and Sleeve for signal ground?
It it's the latter, why are there 3 connectors inside the female jack on the speaker?

Edit: in other words, should I connect the S of the speaker female TRS to chassis (=earth) ground? I'm happy with experimenting and trying 2-3 ways to solder the cable ;-)
(The input will be PC/smartphone/iPod/etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an UN-balanced source, then DO NOT use a TRS plug at the speaker end. Use a TS plug and that will ensure that the connection will work regardless of how the (undocumented) speaker input connector is wired.  This is not a guess.

It would have been helpful if you had revealed the source gear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the former, based on
[Wiring an XLR 1/4" jack combo wall box to a single cable (Neutrik ncj6fi-s)](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38231/wiring-an-xlr-1-4-jack-combo-wall-box-to-a-single-cable-neutrik-ncj6fi-s) and http://hamysound.com/index_htm_files/90861.jpg

But it's only a guess.